# Difference between dynamic and System.Object

Tags: c#, .net, variables, dynamic, .net-4.0

What is the difference between a variable declared as dynamic and a variable declared as System.Object? Running the following function would seem to indicate that both variables get cast to the correct type dynamically:

```
void ObjectTest()
{
    System.Object MyTestVar = "test";
    dynamic MyTestVar2 = "Testing 123";

    Console.WriteLine("{0}", MyTestVar.GetType());
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", MyTestVar2.GetType());

    MyTestVar = 123;
    MyTestVar2 = 321;

    Console.WriteLine("{0}", MyTestVar.GetType());
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", MyTestVar2.GetType());
}
```

Comment: I wrote a post about this some time ago: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/01/25/what-is-the-difference-between-dynamic-and-object-keywords.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference is that `MyTestVar2.ToUpper()` compiles and works, without any explicit casting.

`object` is a normal type.
`dynamic` is a basically a placeholder type that causes the compiler to emit dynamic late-bound calls.

`GetType()` is a normal function defined by the `object` class that operates on the *instance* that you call it on.
`GetType()` is completely unaffected by the declared type of a variable that refers to the object you call it on.  (except for nullables)

Comment: You can call _any_ method on `dynamic` variables.  The code `dynamic x = 3; x.Explode();` will compile perfectly fine

Answer (score 6):

You should probably start with this excellent [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx). The differences can be summed up quite succinctly:

> At compile time, an element that is
>   typed as dynamic is assumed to support
>   any operation.

`System.Object` only has a handful of operations that it supports - `ToString()`, `Equals()`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

The fundamental difference is  **compile-time(for object) vs runtime (for dynamic)** resoulution  of calls. Its also called early vs late binding.  [ Note: add a reference to Microsoft.CSharp for the following code to compile.]

```
   object o = "Hello world";// fine because a derived type can be assigned to a base type
   dynamic d= "Hello world";// fine as well  

   Type otype=o.GetType();// compiles because it confirms that object has a GetType()
   Type dtype=d.GetType();// also compiles but for another reason (i.e.no binding yet)

   string upperd= d.ToUpper(); // compiles because no binding yet ( anything goes :)
   string uppero= o.ToUpper(); // Fails to compile. Object has no ToUpper() method
```

If you comment out the last call , the application should run fine because the CLR , when it reaches the second last call d.ToUpper() at runtime, it  will look for a method ToUpper() in the string type and will find it there (because in the second statement d was assigned a string). The last call did not compile because ToUpper() was being searched in the System.Object type at the compile time which of course will not be there.

Answer (score -2):

The only difference in between object and dynamic.

**In case of object you need to explicit type cast when you are going to retrieve value from object.**

Kindly give a like if you find it suitable.